# Windows XP Home Adobe.Com folder trying to install twice

Tags: adobe-reader

Twice I had to reinstall because Adobe 9 installed for a second time without me requesting or being asked to.  There is a Adobe folder and an Adobe(2) folder.  Installed were Adobe.com; AIS; Reader 9 and Active X.  The system crashes.  I can't do anything. In safe mode, can't uninstall or system restore.  Can't click on anything in regular environment.

Not only will I start looking for alternative pdf reader, and if I can't view a site without active X so be it.  But if I do decide to re-install Adobe, HOW DO I CONFIGURE IT TO NOT UPDATE AUTOMATICALLY????

Day and a half to re-install everything.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience adobe has been second best to Foxit.  I don't have an exact answer for the adobe part of your problem but I can help you out finding an alternative PDF viewer.  http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/